# Menu bar in navbar doesn't work on any html page except for index.html

Tags: html, css, menu

For some reason my list popup menu works on my index page but not on any other html page when the code for the nav bar is the exact same in both htmls. Here is my html

```
<!-- Navigation section
================================================== -->
<div class="nav-container">
   <nav class="nav-inner transparent">

      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="color9">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

              <div class="brand2">
                 <a href="home.html">
                <img src="images/brandl.png" ></a>
            </a>
              </div>

              <div class="navicon">
                <div class="menu-container">

                  <div class="circle dark inline">
                    <i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
                  </div>

                  <div class="list-menu">
                    <i class="icon ion-close-round close-iframe"></i>
                    <div class="intro-inner">
                      <ul id="nav-menu">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
</div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

   </nav>
</div>
</div>
```

and my css

```
.list-menu {
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999999;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.list-menu.reveal-modal {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 999999;
  visibility: visible;
}

.list-menu .ion-close-round {
  font-size: 31px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  right: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is what the popup is supposed to look like.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFKr5.jpg

I've been trying to fix for awhile but can't seem to find a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, but Fixed. [Github Link](https://github.com/Da-vid21/DMAC-clone) So the reason why it didn't work was because the link you gave for the CSS was **css/TheCssFile.css** and the JavaScript was **js/TheJSFile.js**, but your file were in the **root folder**. Even though I can't fully check if the website is functional because of no images, it looks like the website works now.